# do i need to register window event listener in each react component?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns

I have an app written in ReactJS and I sometimes have to add window resize event listener, I now ended up having around 5 components and each one has its own window resize event listener, is there is any better way to handle this, I guess I am missing a design pattern or something that can handle my case .

Your help will be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I used a window resize event listener in my `App.js` file and had it update my `height` and `width` and passing that state to my components that needed it. This is the function that I used:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setWidth(window.innerWidth)
      setHeight(window.innerHeight)
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    return () => { window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize) }
  }, [])
```

It may be better to use `context` to store `height` and `width` if you have many components not directly connected to each other but in my case using state was just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're cleaning up your subscriptions, you're fine.

If you're really concerned about it, you could use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to set up a single subscription, allowing descendant views to consume the value without having to subscribe themselves.

You can also just subscribe in a parent component and pass the values down via props. But make sure to keep the prop passing shallow with this approach. Don't pass a prop down to great great grandchild views, etc. You can end up with a lot of unnecessary re-renders if you're not careful.